# how to set focus on an input field when an error occurred during the form submission

Tags: javascript, html, forms

**1.** I am creating a form validation everything fine, but when an error occurred during the form submission it should be focused on that field. 
**2.** thing is an error message. I am using **span** for showing error message, but when page loaded span also making some space below the input field that is making a distorted. how to hide it when the page loaded and if we don't fill any field show error message show.

Here is my code:

**HTML**

```
<form name="registration" id="form" action="contact.php" method="post" onsubmit="return validateform();">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group col-xs-12 text-left">
                <label for="InputName">Full Name:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
                <br>
                <span id="f_error_msg"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="input-group col-xs-12 text-left">
                <label for="InputEmail">Email Address:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
                <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
                <br>
                <span id="e_error_msg"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="input-group col-xs-12 text-left">
                <label for="InputCompany">Company:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
                <input type="text" name="company" id="company" class="form-control" placeholder="Company">
                <br>
                <span id="c_error_msg"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="input-group col-xs-12 text-left">
                <label for="ProjectDescription">Project Description:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
                <input name="project" id="project" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Project Description">
                <br>
                <span id="p_error_msg"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="input-group col-xs-12 text-left">
                <label for="InputMessage">Message:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
                <input type="text" name="message" id="message" class="form-control" placeholder="I love a team that...">
                <br>
                <span id="m_error_msg"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block" value="Go">
        </div>
    </form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function validateform() {
    var fullname = document.registration.name.value;
    var emailadd = document.registration.email.value;
    var company = document.registration.company.value;
    var project = document.registration.project.value;
    var message = document.registration.message.value;

    if (fullname === null || fullname === "") {
        document.getElementById('f_error_msg').innerHTML = "Please enter Full Name";
        fullname.focus();
        return false;
        document.getElementById('f_error_msg').style.display = "none";
    } 

    var atposition = emailadd.indexOf("@");
    var dotposition = emailadd.lastIndexOf(".");
    if (atposition < 1 || dotposition < atposition + 2 || dotposition + 2 >= emailadd.length) {
        document.getElementById('e_error_msg').innerHTML = "Please enter a valid e-mail address \n atpostion:" + atposition + "\n dotposition:" + dotposition;
        emailadd.focus();
        return false;
        document.getElementById('e_error_msg').style.display = "none";
    } 

    if (company === null || company === "") {
        document.getElementById('c_error_msg').innerHTML = "Please enter your company name";
        company.focus();
        return false;
        document.getElementById('c_error_msg').style.display = "none";
    } 
    if (project === null || project === "") {
        document.getElementById('p_error_msg').innerHTML = "Please enter your project name";
        project.focus();
        return false;
        document.getElementById('p_error_msg').style.display = "none";
    } 
    if (message === null || message === "") {
        document.getElementById('m_error_msg').innerHTML = "Please enter your message here.";
        message.focus();
        return false;
        document.getElementById('m_error_msg').style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use **[focus()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/focus)** function, check working example bellow.

Hope this helps.

---

```js
function validateform() {
var fullname = document.registration.name.value;
var emailadd = document.registration.email.value;
var company = document.registration.company.value;
var project = document.registration.project.value;
var message = document.registration.message.value;

if (fullname === null || fullname === "") {
    resetErrorMsg();

    document.getElementById('f_error_msg').innerHTML = "Please enter Full Name";
    document.registration.name.focus();
    document.getElementById('f_error_msg').style.display = "block";
    return false;
}else{
    document.getElementById('f_error_msg').style.display = "none";
}

var atposition = emailadd.indexOf("@");
var dotposition = emailadd.lastIndexOf(".");

if (atposition < 1 || dotposition < atposition + 2 || dotposition + 2 >= emailadd.length) {
    resetErrorMsg();

    document.getElementById('e_error_msg').innerHTML = "Please enter a valid e-mail address \n atpostion:" + atposition + "\n dotposition:" + dotposition;
    
    document.registration.email.focus();
    document.getElementById('e_error_msg').style.display = "block";
    return false;
}else{
    document.getElementById('e_error_msg').style.display = "none";
}

if (company === null || company === "") {
    resetErrorMsg();

    document.getElementById('c_error_msg').innerHTML = "Please enter your company name";
    document.registration.company.focus();
    document.getElementById('c_error_msg').style.display = "block";
    return false;
}else{
    document.getElementById('c_error_msg').style.display = "none";
}

if (project === null || project === "") {
    resetErrorMsg();

    document.getElementById('p_error_msg').innerHTML = "Please enter your project name";
    document.registration.project.focus();
    document.getElementById('p_error_msg').style.display = "block";
    return false;
} else{
    document.getElementById('p_error_msg').style.display = "none";
}

if (message === null || message === "") {
    resetErrorMsg();
    
    document.getElementById('m_error_msg').innerHTML = "Please enter your message here.";
    document.registration.message.focus();
    document.getElementById('m_error_msg').style.display = "block";
    return false;
} else{
    document.getElementById('m_error_msg').style.display = "none";
}

}

function resetErrorMsg(){
document.getElementById('f_error_msg').style.display = "none";
document.getElementById('e_error_msg').style.display = "none";
document.getElementById('c_error_msg').style.display = "none";
document.getElementById('p_error_msg').style.display = "none";
document.getElementById('m_error_msg').style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<form name="registration" id="form" action="contact.php" method="post" onsubmit="return validateform();">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group col-xs-12 text-left">
                <label for="InputName">Full Name:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
                <br>
                <span id="f_error_msg"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="input-group col-xs-12 text-left">
                <label for="InputEmail">Email Address:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
                <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
                <br>
                <span id="e_error_msg"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="input-group col-xs-12 text-left">
                <label for="InputCompany">Company:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
                <input type="text" name="company" id="company" class="form-control" placeholder="Company">
                <br>
                <span id="c_error_msg"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="input-group col-xs-12 text-left">
                <label for="ProjectDescription">Project Description:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
                <input name="project" id="project" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Project Description">
                <br>
                <span id="p_error_msg"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="input-group col-xs-12 text-left">
                <label for="InputMessage">Message:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
                <input type="text" name="message" id="message" class="form-control" placeholder="I love a team that...">
                <br>
                <span id="m_error_msg"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block" value="Go">
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: yes that is working fine but display:none also not working. document.getElementById('id').style.display = "none"; when i move out that input field or press submit button.

Comment: I guess that you should add it in the `else` clause, check my update please.

Comment: Have other issues also when I fill value in first input and then I move next field and fill the data and again, I move reverse on previous field and remove their data and click submit button then not able to see error message it still show a second field error. and focus showing in the first field. How to fix this issue is there have any solution for that.

Comment: Yes, you should add `.style.display = "block";` check my update.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100139/discussion-between-user01051990-and-zakaria-acharki).

Answer (score 3):

To set focus you can use:

```
document.getElementById('name').focus();
```

If name field has an error.

For span space issue, use display:none initially and when you get the error specify display:inline for that particular error span.